# Any work around for PrimeNG - calendar timepicker hourFormat - 00 displayed for 12:00 AM

Tags: angular, datepicker, primeng

I am using PrimeNG components for an Angular 4 project, and I am struggling with how to use their timepicker. If I bind to a date that is the beginning of the day, I am seeing "00" for the time, instead of 12, even when I have [hourFormat]="12". If [hourFormat]="12", the time should *never* display with 00. Notably, the pop-up for changing the time does display properly. For example, a time of 12:10 AM shows correctly in the popup, but the value in the main control shows as 00:10 AM.

This has been a reported issue since at least 11/20/2017. See https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4486. And I have reported it in their Forum as well: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=54920.

However, I have seen no response and no indication of when the problem will be addressed. So, my question is: Does anybody have a workaround to address this problem until they get around to fixing it?

Comment: This was supposedly fixed. See https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/3fcdc802d805023936d99c80c7d616c7d0ed1a3b. However, the change actually broke 24 hour mode (see comments at that URL), and I can find no indication that any fix is going to be incorporated into PrimeNG version 4.x (required for my Angular 4 projects). I'm out of time, so I must now find some other time picker and use that instead. So sad - I like PrimeNG, and this is not that hard a problem, but they apparently will not fix it. :(